# how does genetic algorithm generate solution..?

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I am using below given GA code. I want to know What sequence ga follow to generate feasible solution.?
 which constraint it will satisfy first linear or non-linear ? If both constraint are not satisfied what kind of solution it gives? 
Is there any procedure to prioritize the constraint (such as one of the constraint must be satisfied).?

```
%cost_1 is Objective function, reli_1 is nonlinear constraint function

%time_1 is matrix containing time of different components and no. of components = NoOfVariable

lb=zeros(NoOfVariables,1);

ub=ones(NoOfVariables,1);

IntCon=[1:NoOfVariables];

[v, fval] = ga(@cost_1, NoOfVariables,time_1,400, [], [], lb, ub, @reli_1,IntCon);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/gads/examples/constrained-minimization-using-the-genetic-algorithm.html):

> The ga solver handles linear constraints and bounds differently from
>   nonlinear constraints. All the linear constraints and bounds are
>   satisfied throughout the optimization. However, ga may not satisfy all
>   the nonlinear constraints at every generation. If ga converges to a
>   solution, the nonlinear constraints will be satisfied at that
>   solution.

This means linear constraints are always satisfied out of the box because the population generation and mating strategies take that into account (unless you implement your own crossover function and mess that up) but non-linear constraints are evaluated after and may not be satisfied. So in the population there is going to be a % of individuals that do not satisfy such linear constraints and these results will be discarded. You can see what % of individuals are discarded too after it runs.

As far as I know there is no way to control this behaviour or swap the order of the evaluation.